# Problem using Microsoft Expression Blend

Tags: expression-blend

I am a newbie to Expression Blend.

When I draw shapes in the workspace, a border appears around the shape.
I want to remove that border.

Please help me in doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a blue square border that is a few pixels outside of the shape? Or is it a black border around the outer surface of the shape? If it is the blue border, you can't get rid of it, this is just the bounding box around it and this will disappear is you deselect the element. If it is the black border, you can remove this by clicking on the "stroke" property in the properties panel and then clicking the button below it to the far left (the square with the diagonal line through it.) This will eliminate the stroke. Hope this helps!